# Using Cairo Regions in python with gi.repository

Tags: python-3.x, introspection, cairo, gobject, pycairo

I can't seem to get cairo regions working in within
using the gintrospection.

For example

```
from gi.repository import cairo

 reg = cairo.Region()
```

will give me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

and trying to get a region from Gdk.get_clip_region() will give me

```
    return info.invoke(*args)
TypeError: Couldn't find conversion for foreign struct 'cairo.Region'
```

What obvious thing am I missing?  I can't find a way to iniatilize the library, and can't imagine you would need to for regions which seem like a simple struct.  I don't know why gdk can't find the cairo types, and am not aware if I"m supposed to show it the way somehow.

Comment: Your not alone it does this for me to.  I think it's a bug, where someone has overlooked a couple of things when writing the gir xml definition files.  It'll probably get fixed if it hasn't already, in future releases.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently you need to use the regular cairo bindings, even when you use introspection for everything else.

So just `import cairo`.

(I'm not sure why `gi.repository.cairo` exists...)

And the "Couldn't find conversion" error will go away when you have all the necessary libraries (e.g. on Ubuntu you need the `python-gi-cairo` package in addition to `python-cairo` (or the equivalent python3 packages)).